# FO block immediately before page footer

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I want to place a certain block right at the bottom of the page (right abover the footer).
I tried using footnote but the result is overlapping the footer. Is there an easy way to achieve this with FO? I'm using Apache FOP 1.1 This is the footnote approach I tried:

```
    <fo:block >
        <fo:footnote>
            <fo:inline></fo:inline>
            <fo:footnote-body><fo:block>Before footer</fo:block></fo:footnote-body>
        </fo:footnote>
    </fo:block>
```

Answer (score 1):

The footnote construct is the correct construct to use.  If you are getting overwrite with the footer, that is a bug in the rendering software.  A footer grows from the bottom of the body area up.  If you have protected the after region from the body region with an appropriate body margin, then you are stuck with faulty software.

I find in my students' work that many forget to shrink the body margin when using perimeter regions.  Perhaps you've made a similar oversight.